# Can you make a GET request in node.js without the HTTP module

Tags: node.js, http, get

Is there a way to make a basic GET request in Node without having to require any additional modules, even the core ones? I know this can be done in vanilla javascript using `XMLHttpRequest()` but that's only available in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no.

You need the ability to create a network socket, and the only ways to do that in Node.js (as far as I'm aware of) are either using the `net` module, or using any C/C++ Addons.

The `http` module with default settings uses the `net` module under the hood.

[XMLHttpRequest is not part of the actual ECMAScript specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Specifications).